# What is a general step-by-step guide to create a custom framework in .NET?

Tags: .net

Is there such a thing as a step-by-step guide to create a custom framework in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)?

I am trying to create one myself, have been reading the materials on the MS website about assemblies and [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) etc. but am getting more and more confused.

I am not trying to do anything particular at this point.  I am just trying to learn how to develop a custom framework.  By framework I meant something like the .NET Framework, or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework.  I know I have to do something with the GAC first, and then make sure that it is strong-named etc.

Comment: I think you are mis-using the term "framework" as most people think of it...can you better describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Frameworks? ughh... http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12

Comment: @ roygbiv, man, i haven't laughed like this in... well, a long time :)

Answer (score 13):

You should to read this book: [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first task is to decide if a framework is appropriate, in most cases it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Writing frameworks are orders of magnitude more complex than writing bespoke software. The biggest problem with creating a framework is that you have to design for backward compatibility. In particular; once you have added something to a framework, it can only be removed with extreme difficulty.

I have written about this [here](https://henrietteharmse.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/the-problem-of-building-a-framework-for-bespoke-software/); where you also can find further references in this regard. I also provide some guidelines for deciding on whether building a framework is appropriate for your organization [here](http://henrietteharmse.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/frameworks-for-bespoke-software-in-the-context-of-enterprise-architecture/).